# Blurry text with SkiaSharp in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, skia, skiasharp

I`m using the SkiaSharp to draw text in WPF.

http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/SkiaSharp-with-Wpf

https://github.com/8/SkiaSharp-Wpf-Example

As you can see the text is not sharp.

[image]

You can easily notice that by comparing the text with the MainWindow test in the title which is sharp.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Pretty easy to see when you zoom in on the bitmaps.  The window title uses ClearType anti-aliasing, the default for a company that makes desktop operating systems.  The window text is rendered with gray-scale anti-aliasing, the default for a company that makes mobile operating systems.  Cats and ugly dogs.  [Check this](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/141).

Comment: Thanks Hans. I'm still trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chances are it is that you are not rendering at a high enough resolution. I experience this on my SurfaceBook display, but not on my external display. You actually have to create a "larger" surface than you actually need. For example, my SurfaceBook has a scaling of 300%, so I have to first get the width of the window, and then multiply by 3:

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/source/SkiaSharp.Views/SkiaSharp.Views.WPF/SKElement.cs#L57-L61

```
var m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
var dpiX = m.M11;
var dpiY = m.M22;
var width = (int)(ActualWidth * dpiX);
var height = (int)(ActualHeight * dpiY);
```

Instead of having to do this yourself, you can make use of the pre-created views in the NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views

You can then just drop in the `SKElement` as in this sample:

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/samples/WPFSample/WPFSample/MainWindow.xaml#L28

```
<views:SKElement x:Name="canvas" PaintSurface="OnPaintCanvas" />
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the good news. I downloaded the latest version from git but I cannot build my solution. The type SK3dView cannot be found.

Comment: Rather just download the samples from: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/releases/tag/v1.56.0 The master branch is unstable, use the v1.56.0 tag if you want to build

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I will look at them when I'm home. Skia looks really promising. I hope I can get it work.

Comment: Do you know if rotated texts are possible or not? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908497/draw-rotated-text-in-skiasharp

Comment: I posted an answer, but `canvas.Rotate(x);` and `canvas.DrawText(text);` are correct. You are just adjusting the drawing matrix.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience If you really want nice and sharp text in WPF, you have to use Text shaping via SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz - which position letters with subpixel precision and then use canvas.DrawPositionedText().