# Print a rotate text with Skia4Delphi

Tags: delphi, skia, skia4delphi

How can I rotate a text using the `TSKPaintBox`? My goal is to print a text rotation of 45°.

I searched on the `skia4delphi` examples, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: [Rotate the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915024/4299358).

Comment: Are you using VCL or FMX?

Comment: Does it make any difference if it’s VCL or FMX? I assume the skia methods are the same.